# My data from database isn't displaying well

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I want to select all my users from users database.. the code works but i think i missed something about my syntax and how i echoed it... so it actually retrieves them , but it produces different table for each data....

i attached the image

```
<?php
            // seclect users from table
            $selectUsers = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY userId DESC";
            $selectUserKwery = mysqli_query($link, $selectUsers);
            $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($selectUserKwery);
            if($userCount > 0){
            while ($userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($selectUserKwery)) { ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>ACTION</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>ACTION</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ucwords($userRow['userId']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ucwords($userRow['userName']); ?></td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td><p><a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></a> | <a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a> | <a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-times"></i> </a> </p></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
                <?php     

            }
            } else if($userCount > 0) {
                        echo '<div class"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">There are no Users yet</div>';
                } ?>
```

[image]

So i want the database result to display in one table

The new result

[image]

Comment: Move all the table tags that don't display returned info out of the loop. From the looks of it, just `<tbody>` and it's sub-tags should be in the loop.

Comment: @user3783243 ah, you're right! Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Its actually *ok* to have multiple `tbody` inside a `table` (for grouping and toggling via css/js etc). But for his purpose, only one will suffice.

Comment: @user3783243.. Thanks .. so i tried your suggestion and i think it worked but am getting one more issure... THIS is a link to the result image on my facebook wall https://web.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1570541653057012&set=a.708730219238164.1073741829.100003035760765&type=3&theater

Comment: thanks for ya suggestion @IncredibleHat

Comment: Solved the issue Guys... Thanks Y'll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting multiple tables because your `<table>` is in the `while`. You should move the structural elements of the table outside of the `while` and just create rows in the `while`. Something like

```
?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>ACTION</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>ACTION</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
<?php while ($userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($selectUserKwery)) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ucwords($userRow['userId']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ucwords($userRow['userName']); ?></td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td><p><a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></a> | <a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a> | <a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-times"></i> </a> </p></td>
                  </tr>
<?php }/* close while */ ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Should do it. You also probably should check that you have a result before building the `<table>`.